# Parse sql parameters from commandtext

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, parameters, sqlcommand

Is it possible to parse sql parameters from plain commandtext?

e.g.

```
//cmdtext = SELECT * FROM AdWorks.Countries WHERE id = @id
SqlCommand sqlc = new SqlCommand(cmdtext);
SqlParameterCollection parCol = sqlc.Parameters //should contain now 1 paramter called '@id'
```

Comment: this may help http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32524/SQL-Parser

Comment: not really - your link just points to a simple statement rebuilding tool

Answer (score 3):

If a SQL Server is available, the best option may be to simply *ask the server what it thinks*; the server has parsing and metadata functions built in, for example [sp_describe_undeclared_parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878260.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with this extention method (since I don't think there's a built in function):

```
public static class SqlParExtension
{
    public static void ParseParameters(this SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        var rxPattern = @"(?<=\= |\=)@\w*";
        foreach (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match item in System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(cmd.CommandText, rxPattern))
        {
            var sqlp = new SqlParameter(item.Value, null);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(sqlp);
        }
    }
}
```

usage:

```
//cmdtext = SELECT * FROM AdWorks.Countries WHERE id = @id
SqlCommand sqlc = new SqlCommand(cmdtext);
sqlc.ParseParameters();

sqlc.Parameters["@id"].Value = value;
```

Comment: Counter example is a *commented out* parameter: `select /*@NotAParameter*/ 1`

Comment: Parameter with between don't work with this :  `where SomeField between @DateFrom and @DateTo`

Answer (score 0):

I will have to make sure about this but I'm sure you must add the range of parameters to the command. Like I say I will have to come back with this but you can try doing something like:

```
// Create a collection of parameters with the values that the procedure is expecting in your SQL client.
SqlParameter[] parameters = { new SqlParameter("@id", qid), 
new SqlParameter("@otherValue", value) };

// Add teh parameters to the command.
sqlc.Parameters.AddRange(parameters)
```

Comment: this is exactly what I tried to avoid. I want to receive the parameter collection from the query itself, not adding each by myself.

Comment: Do you receive the query as a string like you specified in your comment? If so you can use a simple Regular Expression to retrieve the values that is preceded by the '@' character. Im not sure if this is what you want to achieve though.. You can use this Regular Expression to get all of the variables from the select statement '@{1}[A-z]+'

Comment: I have a bunch of queries, where I want to read the parameters, and then iterate through,  to pass the values. To be more precise, is there a built in function for that?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I will play around a bit and let you know what I discover

Answer (score 0):

You would be very welcome to have a look at my **[VS2015 extension, QueryFirst](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eaf390af-afc1-4994-a442-ec95923dafcb)**, that generates wrapper classes from .sql files, **harvesting parameter declarations directly from your sql**. You need to declare your parameters in the --designTime section of  your request, but then **you find them again directly as inputs** to the Execute(), GetOne() or ExecuteScalar() methods. These methods return POCOs with **meaningul property names**. There's intellisense everywhere, and you don't have to **type a line of parameter code, or connection code, or command code, or reader code**, among **NUMEROUS OTHER ADVANTAGES :-)**.